# How to mock ShareDirectoryClient GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync xUnit

Tags: c#, mocking

How to mock ShareDirectoryClient's GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync function in xUnit .Net Core 5

I am trying to mock `public Mock<ShareDirectoryClient> mockShareDirectoryClient = new Mock<ShareDirectoryClient>();`

But facing issue in creating instance of ShareFileItem.

Since ShareFileItem is a abstract class we can not create new instance.

Answer (score 3):

.Net core provides FilesModelFactory factory to create new instance of ShareFileItem.

```
var list = new List<ShareFileItem>();
        list.Add(FilesModelFactory.ShareFileItem(false, "SampleFileName", 1, "11"));
        list.Add(FilesModelFactory.ShareFileItem(false, "SampleDirectory", 1, "11"));

        IReadOnlyList<ShareFileItem> readOnlyList = new ReadOnlyCollection<ShareFileItem>(list);

        List<Page<ShareFileItem>> shareFileList = new List<Page<ShareFileItem>>();
        Page<ShareFileItem> item = Page<ShareFileItem>.FromValues(readOnlyList, string.Empty, null);
        shareFileList.Add(item);

        AsyncPageable<ShareFileItem> pagableList = AsyncPageable<ShareFileItem>.FromPages(shareFileList);

        mockShareDirectoryClient.Setup(s => s.GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync(It.IsAny<ShareDirectoryGetFilesAndDirectoriesOptions>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(pagableList);
```

Comment: I'd upvote this if you add a few comments to make it clearer for the next person.